# How do I work on a unity project on different devices?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been working on a Unity project for school on my home desktop, and I want to be able to work on it in class too. I saved my project in OneDrive and opened up the same project on the school desktop but it was completely empty. The objects I created weren't there, and neither were the scrips nor the materials.

I googled up how to solve this problem and some people were talking about PlasticSCM, I don't really know what it is, but I think my district blocks us from downloading it on school devices.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Versioncontrolintegration.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all the correct files are saved to your online storage space.

The files you need are

- Assets
- Packages
- ProjectSettings
- <s>Assembly-CSharp</s>
- <s>[Your project solution]</s>

*(Edit you only need these three)*

It sounds like at least your assets folder was not properly uploaded.

If Plastic source control is blocked, something like [Git](https://git-scm.com/) (or [GitHub](https://github.com/)) might be allowed.

Source control managers are completly standard in industry and your school teacher *should* be helping you to set one up.

Comment: `Assembly-CSharp` and `[Your project solution]` not .. these will be recreated by Unity .. see [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore) for a list of files and folders that can and should be ignored

Comment: Missed that in the gitignore